# Windows 7 cannot create system image after sysprep

Tags: windows-7-backup, sysprep, imaging

I have 2 PCs of the same make and model from Acer. I lost the admin password on PC-01 and I cannot do a factory restore via F8 (no alt-F10, no password reset disk), so I am thinking to do a `sysprep /generalize` PC-02, create a backup system image on PC-02 shared network folder, then network restore from PC-02 using a Windows 7 installation (boot) disk. (**sanity check: will this work?**)

This is my first time doing a [sysprep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825033.aspx).

On PC-02, I done a `sysprep /generalize /quit`. It progressed through 2 different messages: cleanup phase, generalise phase, then it closes. Although there are no success messages, I do *think* it does completely successfully because if I reboot the computer, it runs the first-run setup.

Ok so back to where sysprep completes and quit. Without restarting the computer, I tried to click on `control panel > backup and restore > create a system image`. However, nothing happens. The backup application doesn't start. Then I tried to run the Acer proprietary eRecovery software, it also does not run. It seems like sysprep did something to them.

But after I reboot the computer and it does its first-run set up, I can use backup and restore and Acer eRecovery again.

At the bottom of the [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825033.aspx), it says

> You must use the Sysprep /generalize command to generalize a complete
>   Windows installation before you can use the installation for
>   deployment to a new computer, whether you use **imaging**, hard disk
>   duplication, or another method.

So I guess there must be a native way to make create the system image?

**EDIT**: What I am trying to do seems to be similar to [these steps](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html).

**EDIT**: Actually resetting the password is secondary. I am taking the opportunity to learn a new method and tool, so would like to know why sysprep behave like this. I can use this method in the future for other issues

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're making a whole lot more work for yourself than you need to.

Forget imaging, if you're unable to reset a local admin accoubnt from a boot cd, you're not going to be doing any imaging.

Just reset the password. It'll be a whole lot easier. Find a copy of MSDaRT or one of the many free password reset tools out there.

Start with UBCD http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

You'll thank me later.

Comment: Actually resetting the password is secondary. I am taking the opportunity to learn a new method and tool, so would like to know why sysprep behave like this. I can use this method in the future for other issues.

Comment: If you really want to learn about imaging start here: http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Videos/MDT2010LiteTouchUnleashedVideos.aspx

Comment: @Jake if you can run sysprep, you have admin rights... why not reset the password then?

Comment: Sysprep only generalizes the system prior to capture. You'd still need a boot media to capture and apply an image. If you really want to learn imaging, you'll need a clean install, MDT, ADK and a Virtual Machine, and days if not weeks to dedicate to learning.

Comment: @CanadianLuke I am running sysprep on another computer.

Comment: @MDTGuy you are not answering the question about sysprep though...

Comment: I am answering the question, if you're looking to "learn" how to image, this is not the right way. Get a clean install going, and install MDT, ADK, and start playing with MDT task sequences, you're wasting time with Sysprep, nobody does Sysprep by hand anymore. DISM is how you capture the image Sysprep just prepares the local install which wont do you any good if you don't have a local admin password.

Comment: you chase your tail with this Sysprep nonsense all day long, but unless you have a boot ISO to capture this image and deploy this image, and a third system to store this image inbwteen those two steps you're going nowhere fast.

Answer (score 0):

The System Image Backup utility is intended for, as its name suggests, backup up a normal Windows environment to an image file so that in the case of system failure, corruption, etc. it can be restored to the same hardware.

The sort of imaging tool that you are looking for is ImageX or DISM (or any of a variety of third party tools) which are intended for creating images of a system for the purpose of deployment, or distribution to other systems. For anyone looking to deploy the Windows operating system, the recommended tool is the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)](http://technet.microsoft.com/windows/dn475741) which is a unified interface for Microsoft deployment technologies, including ImageX and DISM. If you were using MDT to move from one system to another, you would create a Deployment Share on a network location accessible from both. Create a Sysprep and Capture task sequence and run it from the source system, then create a deployment task sequence and run it on the destination system.

In your scenario, an easier alternative could be to use System Image Backup to create an image of the un-Syspreped installation, then to restore it on the destination system, then finally to run Sysprep on the already copied over environment to generalize it. Note that for this to work the image will need to boot on both systems. If they are identical, you will be fine. If not, you may need to at least check the status of the storage drivers to ensure that they are configured for the right mode (AHCI/RAID/IDE).

Answer (score 0):

Jake,

There is a way to do what you want. It requires a second computer.

After running SYSPREP, shut down the PC and remove all the power.
Open the case and REMOVE the hard drive.
Get yourself an external SATA HDD Docking bay like BlacX.
Connect this to the 2nd computer and drop the drive into the Docking bay.
Use the 2nd computer to capture an image of this drive
with either Ghost, Macrium or Acronis.

NOW you can install the drive back into your new computer and boot it up.

When you use the image to restore future drives, make sure the partition on the drive
is a Primary Active partition before you restore the image.

Pete...